# Why can I call ToString() many times on the same object?

Tags: c#, tostring

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string word = "Shazam!";
            Console.WriteLine(word.ToString().ToString().ToString().ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me why I can call ToString() like that many times over? Just curious, thanks!

Comment: you've just got 4 answers which literally says the same thing :) hope one of them helps

Comment: @Joe: Hahaha, yeah. They were all helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `string` itself has a `ToString()` method (all objects do).

You're calling `ToString()` first on `word`, then on the result of that call, then on the result of *that* call etc. Basically each subsequent call acts on the result of the previous one.

It's not limited to `ToString()` of course. For example:

```
int x = new object().ToString().Substring(0, 2).Length;
```

That calls `ToString()` on a new object, then `Substring` on the string that's been returned, then `Length` on that substring.

Answer (score 1):

`.ToString()` returns a string object. It also implements a `.ToString()` which basically returns `this`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Everything is object .
2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx is an object class method.

When you apply toSting on an object it returns an object type string. But it again an object and you can apply toString method on it. 
So your cycle it go infinite. 
As every new thing will be an object.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the `ToString()` method returns a `System.String`, and `System.String` also has a `ToString()` method, so you are calling `ToString()` on the object returned from the previous `ToString()`.

Comment: Fun fact: [`string.ToString` actually seems to `return this`](http://ideone.com/LFhNE). Propably an implementation detail, but nonetheless interesting.

Comment: That is actually not that surprising; since strings are immutable (cannot change), it is not necessary to copy it.

Comment: A rather obvious optimization, yes.

Answer (score 0):

ToString() just returns a string representation as a String object.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx

So word.ToString() returns a String object representing word. The String object has a ToString() function which returns a String object representing the String object... so on.

Answer (score 0):

The `ToString()` method returns a string representing an object.

If you call the `ToString()` method of a string, it returns a string - with the same content as it self. If you do it multiple times you get an other string object basically referring to the very same string.

Answer (score 0):

a function chain is occurring here while calling `ToString()` because`ToString()` returns a string object